# dated dir structure, multi depth

Tags: batch-file

i am new here, i am neither a programmer or computer  professional

i am a amateur photographer and would like to create a folder structure for my photos like below and use a bat file to automate this for every new shoot.

2013-21-31_enter photo shoot info manually
2013-21-31_info from above/2013-21-31_info from above_jpg
2013-21-31_info from above/2013-21-31_info from above_tif
2013-21-31_info from above/2013-21-31_info from above_raw
2013-21-31_info from above/2013-21-31_info from above_bw
2013-21-31_info from above/2013-21-31_info from above_rejects

i really would appreciate your help,

dettki

Comment: and you want it for a custom date? Or to create it only once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a whirl: if you don't want the current date but a date that you enter then remove the REM below.

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime  ^| find "."') do set "dt=%%a"
set "YYYY=%dt:~0,4%"
set "MM=%dt:~4,2%"
set "DD=%dt:~6,2%"
set "HH=%dt:~8,2%"
set "Min=%dt:~10,2%"
set "Sec=%dt:~12,2%"

set datestamp=%YYYY%-%MM%-%DD%
REM set /p "datestamp=Enter date in YYYY-MM-DD format: "
set /p "var=Enter the description: "

for %%a in (jpg tif raw bw rejects) do md "%datestamp%_%var%\%datestamp%_%var%_%%a"

pause
```

Comment: thank you so much foxidrive, it is exactly what i was looking for